# Getting Error MediaPlayerNative( 7313) : Unable to create media player - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, playsound

i'm building a countdown with alarm, i use [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) library for the sound, i try to play a beep sound  at different moments, so i tried this code :

if(timer == "00:50") player.play("bip.wav")

and it didn't work properly, when i restart the app, the sound stop working and i got this error :

```
E/MediaPlayerNative( 6964): Unable to create media player
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 6964): Unexpected error!
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 6964): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to access resource
E/MediaPlayerNative( 7313): pause called in state 0, mPlayer(0xe8091b60)
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 7313): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to access resource
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 7313):    at xyz.luan.audioplayers.WrappedMediaPlayer.setSource(WrappedMediaPlayer.java:423)
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 7313):    at xyz.luan.audioplayers.WrappedMediaPlayer.setUrl(WrappedMediaPlayer.java:61)
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 7313):    at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.handleMethodCall(AudioplayersPlugin.java:82)
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 7313):    at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.onMethodCall(AudioplayersPlugin.java:60)
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 7313):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 7313):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 7313):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 7313):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 7313):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 7313):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
```

this is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

var player = AudioCache();


class Alarm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AlarmState createState() => _AlarmState();
}

class _AlarmState extends State<Alarm> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;



  String get timer {
    Duration duration =
        animationController.duration * animationController.value;
    return "${(duration.inMinutes).toString().padLeft(2,'0')}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";
  }  

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    animationController =
        AnimationController(
            vsync: this,
            duration: Duration(minutes: 1)
        );
  }    
  void Countdown() {
    if (animationController.isAnimating) {
      animationController.stop();
    } else {
      animationController.reverse(
          from: animationController.value == 0.0
              ? 1.0
              : animationController.value);
    };
  }
 

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [

            Align(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 90,
                  ),
                  AnimatedBuilder(
                      animation: animationController,
                      builder: (_, Widget child) {
                      **if (timer == "00:50") player.play("bip.wav");**
                        return Text(timer,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 100.0,
                            )    
                        );    
                      }
                  ),
                  Container(

                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment:
                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FloatingActionButton(
                          elevation: 0.0,
                          child: AnimatedBuilder(
                              animation: animationController,
                              builder: (_, Widget child) {
                                return Icon(
                                  animationController
                                      .isAnimating
                                      ? Icons.pause
                                      : Icons.play_arrow,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 50,
                                );
                              }),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          splashColor: Colors.white,
                          onPressed: () {

                            Countdown();

                            setState(() {
                              Icon(animationController
                                  .isAnimating
                                  ? Icons.pause
                                  : Icons.play_arrow);
                            });
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: try with an older version of audioplayers, 0.10.0 or 0.12.0 , i don't know why, but for me it works well until this moment, you can see it here https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/issues/661

Answer (score 0):

You should use a

`Timer.periodic( ...)`

so you can play the sound each 10 mins.

Comment: the solution is ... if ( timer == "00:50" ) player.play('bip.wav') return Text(timer) . but it didn't work well, i'm getting this error hopefuly you can help : 
E/MediaPlayerNative( 9973): Unable to create media player
E/AudioplayersPlugin( 9973): Unexpected error!